# web filter issue of my Telecom ISP

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

This issue is based upon my Telecom ISP,

I found a security hole in my Telec ISP to access internet for free, which is  any connections any port that uses HTTP protocol is allowed for free. But other than HTTP services like, HTTPS, ICMP, P2P is blocked which left me over a situation that I can only use HTTP Proxies (Web Proxy & Normal Proxy) with any port for connecting to internet.

I can't connect to VPN as TCP & UDP is also Blocked. Tried to connect to VPN using HTTP Proxies (CONNECT) but it also fails as CONNECT method is based on SSL Protocol.

TCP VPN log:

```
Mon Apr 13 07:08:11 2015 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]91.194.91.55:3128 [nonblock]
Mon Apr 13 07:08:11 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1428889091,TCP_CONNECT,,,
Mon Apr 13 07:08:12 2015 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]91.19*.**.***:3128
Mon Apr 13 07:08:12 2015 Send to HTTP proxy: 'CONNECT 176.126.237.207:80 HTTP/1.0'
Mon Apr 13 07:08:17 2015 recv_line: TCP port read timeout expired
Mon Apr 13 07:08:17 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,init_instance] received, process restarting
Mon Apr 13 07:08:17 2015 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1428889097,RECONNECTING,init_instance,,
Mon Apr 13 07:08:17 2015 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

Is ISP can block / filter my SSL connections using Web Filter?

Is there a way to bypass the filtering and use the Internet via any techniques like tunneling ?

Can I use the Blocked services like P2P through bypassing the filter?

Please provide me a solution! Thank you in Advance.

Note:

The problem is only on free mode, when i am using the paid internet all services are working with any throttling / filtering.

Some proxies usually not support the CONNECT protocol, so i checked them with Paid Services of same ISP it works very well & connects to VPN.

Tried downloading torrent with Bittorrent (by HTTP proxy) is not connecting in free mode but works in paid mode.

Comment: I really can't think of any *secure* way of doing this. As you say, anny kind of secure connection is blocked which rules out almost everything. You could probably set up a machine on a cloud host and possibly set up some kind of remote desktop http server and browse the internet from that. Chances are the machine would cost more then your paid internet access though.

Comment: I think this very question would be more relevant and get more feedback in a Telecommunication site, as the proposal here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications

Answer (score 0):

I believe ISP can block SSL connections. You can actually use the telnet program to test what works. See here for some examples: http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/

Comment: sorry bro..  i havnt used telnet before. could you please eloborate ???

Comment: The comment box sucks! It won't let me enter Enter! When I press enter it submits the content. Anyway, first enter `telnet www.google.com 80`, then `GET / HTTP/1.1\n`, then `Host: www.google.com`, then double returns. You'll see google home page displayed in your terminal. To try SSL proxy, replace `GET / HTTP/1.1` with `CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: Tried Telnet session with PUTTY. None of it works after double returns it says CONNECTION WAS CLOSED BY HOST. With my Broadband ISP (paid service) all works quite well.

Comment: I also want to add that my telecom ISP doesnot resolve the web address. i.e when i send www.4ever****.com in browser it doesnt even connects to it, while i entered the ip address of that web proxy (192.3*.***.***) it connects and loads the web proxy.