# Strange issue in Downloading via HTTP(GET) proxy in IDM (int.D manager) vs IDA (Int.D accelerator)

Tags: proxy, download, http-proxy

before stating my problem, i want to quote that my ISP allows downloading files only via HTTP (GET) Proxies. Visit my previous thread for my ISP issue  { [web filter issue of my Telecom ISP](https://superuser.com/questions/900843/web-filter-issue-of-my-telecom-isp) }.

Iam using IDM for downloading but still i want a alternate Download manager. So i suggested to use IDA. Same as using HTTP proxy for downloading.

I came up with a strange issue that using HTTP proxy in IDM, downloads goes on smoothly with no problem. when i use the same in IDA no data is received, Keeps on Re-connecting.

Here the logs of my download:

### Internet Download Manager (IDM) log:

```
Folder F:\IDM\Temp\DwnlData\ray\Pr.part3_7496\ was created.
Rebuilding old downloaded file parts...
Connecting...
Windows 6.2
v6.23b11   Time: Thu May 07 15:03:24.186 2015 (1430991204 sec)
Url http://sv3-free.max-debrid.com /free/rapidgator/708fdcef04cdbc561f38/Pr.rar
User : anonymous, password :xxx
Downloading via proxy server 176.100.100.242:3128
C0:Connecting...
C0:Checking connect, socket = 1164 
C0:Connect OK.
C0:Send GET...
Time: 1430991204.764
C0:SC step12
C0:C0:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
C0:Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 09:33:39 GMT
C0:Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
C0:X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
C0:Pragma: no-cache
C0:Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 1971 02:00:00 GMT
C0:Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
C0:Cache-Control: private
C0:Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
C0:Accept-Ranges: bytes
C0:Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Max-Debrid_Pr.rar
C0:Content-Length: 766484924
C0:Content-Type: application/octet-stream
C0:X-Cache: MISS from bgp.proxy
C0:X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from bgp.proxy:3128
C0:Via: 1.1 bgp.proxy (squid/3.4.11)
C0:Connection: keep-alive
C0:
C0:Receiving data...
Time: 1430991207.33
Optional connections, connecting...
C1:Connecting...
time 1430991207
time 1430991207
Receiving data...
Insert next chunk in list
s9
Adding record to registry with ID 1, startPos 440590, nextID -1
Updating record with num 0: set ID 0, startPos 0, nextID 1
C1:Send GET...
Time: 1430991207.441
C1:SC step12
C1:440590-766484923, 440590-766484923
C0:Receiving data...
C1:Waiting response...
time 1430991209, speed 118748, downl 276619 Bytes
C0:conn. 0 dowload complete
C0:The file chunk of connection 1 is reassigned to connection 0.
C1:stratPos=440590, endPos=766484923, downloaded=0
C1:Disconnect.
Deleting record with num 1
Updating record with num 0: set ID 0, startPos 0, nextID -1
set next->conn->lpListItem = NULL
C1:Reusing connection.
C1:Connecting...
Insert next chunk in list
s9
Adding record to registry with ID 2, startPos 383499341, nextID -1
Updating record with num 0: set ID 0, startPos 0, nextID 2
C1:Send GET...
Time: 1430991210.944
C1:SC step12
C1:383499341-766484923, 383499341-766484923
time 1430991212, speed 121035, downl 604959 Bytes
C1:HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
C1:Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 09:33:45 GMT
C1:Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
C1:X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
C1:Pragma: public
C1:Expires: 0
C1:Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
C1:Cache-Control: private
C1:Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
C1:Accept-Ranges: bytes
C1:Content-Length: 382985583
C1:Content-Range: bytes 383499341-766484923/766484924
C1:Content-Type: application/octet-stream
C1:X-Cache: MISS from bgp.proxy
C1:X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from bgp.proxy:3128
C1:Via: 1.1 bgp.proxy (squid/3.4.11)
C1:Connection: keep-alive
C1:
C1:Receiving data...
```

### Internet Download Accelerator (IDA)

```
1 07/05/2015 15:06:14 Download state changed to Downloading
2 07/05/2015 15:06:15 Start new section [1]
3 07/05/2015 15:06:15 Start connection to 176.100.100.242:3128 [1]
4 07/05/2015 15:06:15 Connecting to 176.100.100.242:3128 [1]
5 07/05/2015 15:06:15 Connected [1]
6 07/05/2015 15:06:15 GET http://sv3-free.max-debrid.com/free/rapidgator/708fdcef04cdbc561f38/Pr.rar HTTP/1.0
                      User-Agent: IDA
                      Accept: */*
                      Accept-Encoding: identity
                      Referer: http://sv3-free.max-debrid.com/free/rapidgator/708fdcef04cdbc561f38/
                      Pragma: no-cache
                      Cache-Control: no-cache
                      Host: sv3-free.max-debrid.com
```

As you can clearly see that in **IDM** data is received but in **IDA** none is happenned. Please help me by explaining the issue and resolving it.

**Thank you in advance** ;) :)